# Node.js express console.log doesn't show anything

Tags: node.js, express

Sometimes console.log doesn't show messages.
In app.listen everything works fine but in app.post - NOT.
Please help to figure it out!

**Node.js 12.14.1
Express 4.17.1**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require('request');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on 3000 port");
})

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    console.log("POST triggered!");
    //There is NO any message in my Terminal
    res.send('POST request to homepage');
    //It works properly

})
```

Comment: How do you test your server and reach the `POST /` route?

Comment: Is this `console.log("Server is running on 3000 port");` printed in the console?

Comment: The right way to show that your question has been answered is to *accept an answer* (yes, even your own). Not to edit words into the title.

Answer (score 2):

You're running a nodejs express server, the console is supposed to be the the console of your server, check you Vs Code's Console if you're on VS Code.

Hit localhost:port/ and watch your editor's or cmd's console, from where you started the server.

Comment: OP says `In app.listen everything works fine`. I guess he knows where the logs are.

Comment: Yes, I posted solution below! Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0):

I am using a windows new terminal and it's a thing.
Somehow my server was dis-attached from console and lived on his own, so all messages it was sending to nowhere!

Solution is to kill all node processes!

Answer (score 0):

Both Get and Post Requests are working fine. You should have to Post requests from the postman and get from the browser. Because by default browser request is Get.

Code -

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
// const request = require('request');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server is running on 3000 port");
})

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("get triggered!");
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log("POST triggered!");
  //There is NO any message in my Terminal
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
  //It works properly

})
```

[image: Postman]
[image]